# api integration with alamofire api function called but api not called

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Hello i am implementing API using `Alamofire` and i have created one function for call API as below

```
func callHistoryAPI(){
        print("Called")
        guard let tonum = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedNumber") else { return }
        guard let fromnum = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "mob_num") else { return }
        let params = ["to": tonum, "from": fromnum]
        print(params)
        AF.request(calllist, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON(completionHandler: {(response) in
            switch response.result{
            case.success(let value):
                let json  = JSON(value)
                print(json)
                let data = json["data"]
                if data == []{
                    self.viewNoRecords.isHidden = false
                }else{
                    self.viewNoRecords.isHidden = true
                    data.array?.forEach({ (hlist) in
                        let h_list = HistoryModel(sid: hlist["sid"].stringValue, forwardedFrom: hlist["forwardedFrom"].stringValue, from: hlist["from"].stringValue, duration: hlist["duration"].stringValue, call_date: hlist["call_date"].stringValue)
                        self.historyData.append(h_list)
                    })
                }
                self.tblListView.reloadData()
            case.failure(let error):
                basicErrorAlertWith(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, controller: self)
            }
        })
    }
```

and than i am calling this function inside `viewdidLoad()` so function is called as i `print("Called")` inside function but api not calling is there any solution?

Comment: You have printed params, please check it is printed, You have used guard let so if your userdefault  key selectedNumber or mob_num is nil then it will return from function and your api will not call

Comment: but params not printed i have debug it i am not able reach to params

Comment: Ok, that means your selectedNumber or mob_num key value is null. Please try to debug both values ,and check value is store properly in UserDefault or not

Comment: Once you get your params value then your API will definitely call

Comment: i figure it out issue is api is not call on main thread i not i called in main thread and it work for me